# Retrieving only enabled accounts from Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am able to get all users from Azure Active Directory using ActiveDirectoryClient.

Is there a way to get only enabled users from azure AD in ASP.NET MVC or after retrieving all users, filter them as enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `AccountEnabled` boolean property of a `User` object indicates if a user is enabled for sign-in. This attribute supports filtering on the service side (indicated by "($filter)", in the "Supports" column of the [`User` entity reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity)), (so there's no need to do client-side filtering).

In the following sample, we iterate over all users that are enabled (`graphClient` is an instance of `ActiveDirectoryClient`):

```
// Iterates over all enabled users.
var users = await graphClient.Users.Where(u => u.AccountEnabled == true).ExecuteAsync();
do
{
    foreach (var user in users.CurrentPage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enabled user: {0}", user.UserPrincipalName);
    }
    users = await users.GetNextPageAsync();
} while (users != null);
```

If you use Fiddler (or any other traffic analyzer), you'll see that this translates into the following GET request to the Azure AD Graph API:

```
https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/users()
    ?$filter=accountEnabled%20eq%20true
    &api-version=1.6
```

The part that is doing the filtering (minus the URL encoding)  is:

```
$filter=accountEnabled eq true
```

Comment: Great help @Philippe Signoret, i was able to make above query but i missed to  block user account in azure active directory. here is one more query, in my project windows server active directory users have been synced to azure active directory. so if one will disable user in windows server active directory than after sync to azure ad. Is disabled user reflect as blocked user in Azure AD or not?

Comment: Yes, once the change has been synced, it will be reflected in the `AccountEnabled` property for the corresponding `User` object in Azure AD.

Answer (score 2):

Should be.
[Here is the list of all properties of the User object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity), along with indication which of them support filtering ($filter)

[And here is documentation on how to use filtering, paging, querying](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options).

And finally, the [interactive Azure AD Graph API Rest Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsers) for the GetUsers operation using which you can experiment with your queries.

At the end your `$filter` query parameter should have value of `accountEnabled eq true` (at least - this is enough to get only enabled accounts, you can additional conditions if you like to filter more).

And whole GET request should like something like:

> https://graph.windows.net/contoso.com/users?api-version=2013-11-08&$filter=accountEnabled%20eq%20true

Comment: Great help @astaykov :),i asked same to Philippe. please help me for following: in my project windows server active directory users have been synced to azure active directory. so if one will disable user in windows server active directory than after sync to azure ad. Is disabled user reflect as blocked user in Azure AD or not?